# How to resolve "import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager"

Tags: java, swt

I have a SWT application and it was working fine. I was using Google WindowBuilder Pro to build the application windows. Today I was trying to do some update on my application. So when I open it I found an error saying "`import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager the import cannot be resolved`". But it was working previously. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem?

I am using Eclipse Helios for the development.

Answer (score 7):

This helper class is generated inside your project by WindowBuilder as soon as you change for example the font of a label.

The code for the class can also be found by googling for the name, for example here:
https://github.com/vogellacompany/codeexamples-java/blob/master/de.vogella.databinding.windowbuilder.example/src/com/swtdesigner/SWTResourceManager.java

Comment: above source link is not available.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The workaround i used was to create a new class (of the same type, in my case SWT Application Window) and copy all the code from the faulty class to the new one.

Answer (score 0):

download the window builder jar file and add it to your project. (right click the project, choose properties, and click add variable, then choose the jar file your downloaded)

Answer (score 0):

I had some problem. I tried to find the jar and fix the problem. But I was not able to locate the jar. Instead I found the source in this [link](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.beanfabrics/beanfabrics-swt/1.4.0/com/swtdesigner/SWTResourceManager.java/?v=source&disposition=attachment) downloaded and put in same package structure in my project.

It work for me, Download the source from below link :
http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.beanfabrics/beanfabrics-swt/1.4.0/com/swtdesigner/SWTResourceManager.java/?v=source&disposition=attachment

Hope it may be help full for other also.

Answer (score 0):

There is jar files in internet. But I having problem with those. What I did to solve this,

download the `SWTResourceManager` java file from the  [github- click this](https://github.com/JazzCore/jasmine-history-reader/blob/master/src/org/eclipse/wb/swt/SWTResourceManager.java). Then I edit some lines, those are:

1. In **SWTResourceManager.java** file, change `package
   org.eclipse.wb.swt;` to your package name.
2. And in **whatever.java** your java file you are going to use that
   library, remove `import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;` this line or change to your package.

Now you good to go..

Comment: I am adding this answer years lately. Why? I had this problem and I found this question but I couldn't solve from these answer(not clearly mentoned where to find). So I resolve this, I thought it would be helpful to someone who searching for...